# accessing files in a google drive directory that is shared with anyone with link can view

Tags: android, google-drive-api, app-inventor

I teach how to make apps with app inventor 2. My students have google id's and access to google drive. I would like them to be able to create an app that lists the contents of a shared google drive folder (they have the link to the folder), select one of the files and download the file. The purpose is to drive a hangman like app that uses a delimited file that contains a set of vocabulary words and hints.

I have been able to create this app using the embeddedfolderview option (https://drive.google.com/embeddedfolderview?id=) and then parsing the response to get the names and id's of the files. Then issuing a second request to actually download the content of the file.

I have a working android app that they could adapt by just changing the link to point to their folder.

Does this violate any agreement with google drive?

In summary, I'm using uri's to access google drive and then download content. Is this allowed?

Answer (score 0):

The way Google Drive works is that any data can be put on different access levels.

To find these Link sharing options go to your [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/), left click on a file and select 'Share'. Then click 'Advanced'.

[image]

When a file is 'Public on the web' it is therefore legal to use it in any way you like. Also if you would like, the file can be put in a public but still closed group by sharing with 'Anyone with the link'.